# What is the easiest way to install wxPython 2.9.5.0 onto a Ubuntu Raring (13.04) system?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, wxpython

wxPython installation instructions vary so much; even the official instructions don't work and fail with 404:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://apt.wxwidgets.org/dists/raring-wx/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://apt.wxwidgets.org/dists/raring-wx/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://apt.wxwidgets.org/dists/raring-wx/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What is the easiest way to get this done?